running expect spawn in docker alpine - no such file or directory
I'm new to bash testing and wanted to create a docker image to test a cli. I discovered 'expect' and wanted to try it against this example bash script. Only problem is its failing to spawn a file.
data/que.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name"
read $REPLY
echo "Enter your age"
read $REPLY
echo "Enter your salary"
read $REPLY

data/test.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
 
set timeout 2
spawn /data/que.sh
expect "Enter your name\r"
send -- "I am Steve\r"
expect "Enter your age\r"
send -- "2\r"
expect "Enter your salary\r"
send -- "10k\r"
expect eof

docker-compose.yml
services:
  linux-expect:
    container_name: cont-alpine-linux-expect
    image: img-alpine-linux-expect
    build:
      context: .

Dockefile
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --update nodejs-current npm

USER root
RUN apk update && apk add expect

RUN mkdir data
COPY data /data

CMD ["node", "-e","setTimeout(() => console.log(999999), 99999999)"]
# Just run temporary timeout so we can interact with script


terminal command

docker-compose up --build

new terminal

docker exec -it cont-alpine-linux-expect sh
expect data/test.sh

I am getting an error to find this file, but it does exist.
I am the root user.
Error

"spawn /data/que.sh"
(file "data/test.sh" line 4)


The problem is that it can't find bash. You have
#!/bin/bash

as the first line in your script, so the shell looks for bash to run it. But bash isn't installed in Alpine images.
You can see if your script runs with /bin/sh. I believe that's the ash shell in Alpine images. If that doesn't work, you can install bash in the image using apk.

thankyou. rookie mistake. Can I ask also - if the test were to fail - ie i expect the wrong text, how do I capture that this fails? Currently it just gets stuck and doesn't throw any kind of error

Sorry, I'm not familiar with expect, so I don't know.

This is wrong:
read $REPLY

the read command takes variable names as arguments.
After the first echo, because REPLY is empty, you have the bare read, which will use the default REPLY variable.
After the second echo, bash sees read I am Steve

the I variable gets the value 2
the am and Steve variables get empty values.

After the third echo, because REPLY did not get used after the previous read, you have again read I am Steve

the I variable gets the value "10k"
the am and Steve variables get empty values.

